# How to use the properties of a passed list of known objects

Tags: c#, list, object

this might be a simple fix but I can't seem to find anything about it. I am very new to C# if it's not obvious.

I'm passing a list of objects from my main method but I haven't been able to use the properties of the objects.  I want to use a property called "Asset"  This is my code:

```
    private void GetDueDates(List<object> objects)
    {
        Type myType = objects.GetType();
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

        if(props.Contains(Asset)
        {
             doStuff();
        }
    }
```

I thought if I got the type of object then I could use the correct property but that didn't work. Do I even need to find which type it is?

Comment: Why are you passing a List<object>?  If you must accept a type that has the Asset property then why not have something like an IAsset and then pass a List<IAsset>.

Comment: Why not just List<Asset> instead?

Comment: I need to use all the properties of the objects, I figured if I asked how to use one property I could use them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Asset` isn't a valid expression here, unless you've actually got a variable called `Asset` somewhere. You want to find out if the *name* of any property is `Asset`... and you want to do it on *each* object, not on the list itself:

```
foreach (var item in objects)
{
    var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
    var assetProperty = props.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Asset");
    if (assetProperty != null)
    {
        var value = assetProperty.GetValue(item, null);
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're only looking for a public property, you can pass the name to `GetProperty`:

```
foreach (var item in objects)
{
    var assetProperty = item.GetType().GetProperty("Asset");
    if (assetProperty != null)
    {
        var value = assetProperty.GetValue(item, null);
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Having said this, it would be cleaner if you had an interface or something similar:

```
var assetItems = objects.OfType<IHasAsset>();
foreach (var assetItem in assetItems)
{
    var asset = assetItem.Asset;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am only using public properties, I think your second code example is my best bet. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you know what type all of the objects in `objects` should be, then `objects` should be a list of that type, instead of a list of `object` (so `List<MyType>`). At this point, you can simply refer to `objects[0].Asset`, since all of the objects in the list are of type `MyType`.

If you still want `objects` to be a `List<object>`, then you'll have to typecast each of the objects in the list to a `MyType` in order to use the `Asset` property of the `MyType` class: `((MyType)objects[0]).Asset`.

If you do this, and you aren't sure that all of the objects in the list are actually of type `MyType`, you need to check that:

```
if (objects[0] is MyType)
{
    // do stuff with ((MyType)objects[0]).Asset
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I found that Jon Skeet had a good example that matched what I want to do.